# How to search with xpath in given html element?

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following code:

```
    HtmlPage searchPage = mainWebClient.getPage(searchUrl);
    List<HtmlListItem> lis = searchPage.getByXPath("//div[@id='mainContent']//li[contains(@id, 'results-listing')]");
    for (HtmlListItem li : lis) {
        List<Object> linkXPath = li.getByXPath("//a[contains(@class, 'itemlink')]/@href");
    }
```

On the fourth line I want to search with XPath only in the li and not in the whole page. If i put there: 
searchPage.getByXPath("//a[contains(@class, 'itemlink')]/@href");
the result will be the same. How to search not in the whole document but only in the li ?

Comment: Please share you html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index rather for each.

```
searchPage.getByXPath("(//div[@id='mainContent']//li[contains(@id, 'results-listing')])[" + index + "]//a[contains(@class, 'itemlink')]/@href");
```

Comment: Updated the answer to use the index directly in the xpath. You have to change the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem came because the use of an [absolute location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath) (basicaly, a location path starting with `/`).

You need a relative location path. Use:

```
descendant::a[contains(@class, 'itemlink')]/@href
```

Or with abbreviations

```
.//a[contains(@class, 'itemlink')]/@href
```